# Bijective hash function

Tags: c, hashtable, hash-function

The function that returns the hash can return the same index for different id values:

```
hash(id) = id%ARRAY_SIZE
```

Is there a way to have the hash function being bijective. I thought of:

```
hash(id) = id
```

But I do not have contiguous id values. Does someone have a better solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A hash function is any function that can be used to map data of arbitrary size to data of fixed size.

[Hash function on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)

So by definition, a hash function cannot be bijective, because its domain is infinite, while its range is finite.

Comment: While true, for any fixed finite set of inputs there does exist a perfect hash.